# Under "Activities," after clicking on own icon, there is a "tags" tab, what do all the numbers indicate?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page, formatting

Just Curious:

What do all the different numbers surrounding the tags listed (under my personal activities) indicate?  For example, See below:

[image]

I know that the 16 in the highlighted image that pops up indicates that this tag has been used in 16 questions, but I don't quite get the rest. Can someone just clarify the following?

- What does the **4** on the **LEFT** of "coloration-discoloration" imply?
- What does the **5** on the **RIGHT** of "coloration-discoloration" imply?
- What does **348 tags** indicate at the **top**?
- What does it mean when it has a **0** on the **left of the tag?**
- What does it mean if it has a **0** on the **right of the tag?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple answer:

- The **4** means you have 4 net votes (upvotes minus downvotes) on your answers to questions which have the tag.
- The **5** means you have written 5 posts (in your case, [four questions and one answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:6563+[coloration-discoloration])) that use the tag.
- **348** (now 353) means that the total number of unique tags used by questions you've asked and question you've answered is 348.
- A **0** on the left of a tag name means your answer score is 0 for that tag.
- There should not be a **0** to the right of the tag name. It would indicate that you have never asked a question or answered a question that uses that tag, and thus the tag wouldn't show up in your list of tags in the first place.